# Find a succession to get a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, martingales

Let $(S_n)$ be a simple and symmetric random walk on $\Bbb Z$ and $(F_n)_{n≥0}$ its natural filtration. Find a sequence of real numbers $(\alpha_n)_n$ such that the process $(Y_n)_{n≥0}$ defined by $Y_n: = S^3_n + \alpha_n · S_n$ is a martingale.

I understand the idea is show that $E(Y_{n+1}|Y_n, ..., Y_0)=Y_n$, so replacing

$$
E(S^3_{n+1} + \alpha_{n+1} · S_{n+1}|Y_n, ..., Y_0)=E(S^3_{n+1} |Y_n, ..., Y_0)+E(\alpha_{n+1} · S_{n+1}|Y_n, ..., Y_0)
$$
and I can remove the $\alpha_n$ because it is a sequence of real numbers, then i have
$$
E(S^3_{n+1} + \alpha_{n+1} · S_{n+1}|Y_n, ..., Y_0)=E(S^3_{n+1} |Y_n, ..., Y_0)+ \alpha_{n+1}·E(S_{n+1}|Y_n, ..., Y_0)
$$
but since $S_n$ is a symmetrical walk, this is a martingale. Finally
$$
E(S^3_{n+1} + \alpha_{n+1} · S_{n+1}|Y_n, ..., Y_0)= S^3_n+\alpha_{n+1}·S_n
$$
From all the above i conclude that $\alpha_{n+1}=\alpha_n$. Then it can be a constant sequence.

My proof is ok? I appreciate the help.

Comment: It looks like you're using $E[S_{n+1}^3 | Y_n,...,Y_0] = S_n^3$.  Are you sure that's the case?

Comment: I actually thought so because the walk is symmetrical, no?

Comment: It is, but I don't think that implies $S_n^3$ is a martingale.  Try computing the conditionaly expectation by writing $S_{n+1}^3 = (S_n+X_{n+1})^3$ where $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal F_n$ and $P(X_{n+1}=1)=P(X_{n+1}=-1)=\frac 12$.

Answer (score 1):

We must find a sequence $(\alpha_n)_{n \in\ \mathbb{N}}$ such that
$$E[Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{A}_n]=Y_n \ \ \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
By taking the conditional expectations
$$E[Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{A}_n]=E[S_{n+1}^3+S_{n+1}\alpha_{n+1}|\mathcal{A}_n]=E[S_{n+1}^3|\mathcal{A}_n]+\alpha_{n+1}S_n$$
$$E[Y_{n}|\mathcal{A}_n]=S_{n}^3+\alpha_{n}S_{n}$$
Ultimately we set
$$E[Y_{n+1}-Y_n|\mathcal{A}_n]=E[S_{n+1}^3|\mathcal{A}_n]-S^3_n+(\alpha_{n+1}-\alpha_n)S_n=0$$
So we find recursively
$$\alpha_{n+1}=\alpha_n-\frac{E[S_{n+1}^3|\mathcal{A}_n]-S^3_n}{S_n}$$